# How to deal with spiteful users?

Tags: discussion

I recently pointed out in a comment to an answer ([Create a string for a time variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442101/create-string-for-a-time-variable)) that the poster of that answer (Neel) had copied it from the answer of another user, including a spelling error the original answerer (Fahad) had made. At first he denied it, and after I pointed out that his copy answer also included the original error, he deleted his answer. Which would be fine. But now I have received downvotes on four of my answers in quick succession (which are quite unrelated to each other) and I strongly suspect Neel is downvoting my answers out of spite. What should I do in such a situation?

Comment: Don't do a thing. Serial downvoting is automatically reversed by the system. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: Thanks @Bart, is there a threshold for serial downvoting? If there is, would four downvotes fall below that? Is there a way to alert a serial downvoting case if the system fails to detect it? By the way if you posted your comment as an answer, I'd be glad to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: The post I link to does explain what to do if the downvotes are not reversed within 24 hours. The exact details of the algorithm are kept a secret however.

Comment: @Bart Fair enough.